# Angular: 404 Error Page when accessing route

Tags: angular

I have angular app (with spring boot on backend)

here are my routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'intro', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },


// LANGUAGES
{ path: 'english', component: LanguageComponent },
{ path: 'spanish', component: LanguageComponent },

// CITIES
{ path: 'alexandria', component: CityComponent },
{ path: 'ankara', component: CityComponent }];

export const router: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false, initialNavigation: true });
```

And now the funny behavior:

When I route in the app ( = clicking the button/link tags having routerLink ) everything works ok, but when I directly insert url into the browser, I got following:

- **localhost:8080/english** -> Whitelabel Error Page (default spring boot 404 page). (for any language)
- **localhost:8080/alexandria** -> Works as expected (for any city)

---

When I run the frontend on a separate server (localhost:4200), everything works as expected.

Comment: You must configur your spring boot to redirect everything to index.html

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that configuration. Thanks! You as write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your spring boot to redirect everything to `index.html`.

Because when the request hits your server, unless you redirect to angular app (`index.html`), Angular app won't run, then your routing configuration in Angular isn't worth.